# SAS HLM--why is my UN(2,2) zero?

Tags: mixed-model, covariance, sas

I am estimating a random intercept and slope model using sas proc mixed. I've already plotted the data and looked at the ICC and decided that a random intercept and possibly a random slope make sense. But when I estimated the random intercept+slope model, the covariance parameter estimates are really weird, like the following. Can anyone tell me what this might mean? Does this suggest a random slope is not appropriate in this case?

ps. Output also said "the converge criteria met". In the past I have seen models resulted in "Estimated G matrix is not positive definite", suggesting one or more variance components should be removed, but not this time.

My model is using environmental features and personal characteristics to predict mood. My data structure is day of sampling nested within individual. Every participant took 3-4 sample days, and I have 150 participants. Response var is mood (continuous), explanatory vars are: level 1-- environment, outdoortime; level 2-- gender, race, ses, age, carownership. The model I am fitting is here:

```
PROC MIXED data=study2 METHOD=ML COVTEST noclprint;  
  CLASS id event weekday racec sesc gender car dog grade;  
  MODEL poms = environment outdoortime car gender racec sesC /SOLUTION  ddfm=sat;  
  RANDOM INTERCEPT environment/SUB=ID TYPE=UN G GCORR;   
RUN;
```

[image]

Comment: This is hard to follow. What are "UN(,)"? What are your variables? Can you say more about your situation, your data & your model?

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the questions. The covariance matrix here is the intercept-environment variances/covariances.

Comment: What is the `environment` variable? Is it categorical? It looks like it might be (& that makes conceptual sense of the name), but it isn't listed in the `CLASS` statement.

Comment: I personally find the absence of a standard error somewhat alarming/indicative of a convergence problem. But my experience doing multilevel modeling in SAS is limited. Have you tried the REML estimation method rather than ML?

Comment: Thanks Gung. The environment variable is a continuous variable. It is the key measure of my study--the other measures are all kind of controls. And I know from literature that the association between environment and mood might be modified by individual level differences-- that is why I am testing a random slope here.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I will try REML estimation and see how it goes!